# Can some one help- how to extract Token from API response

Tags: regex, jmeter

**How can i extract token in jmeter using Regular expression extractor**

{"message":"Token Retrieved","data":{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkZXZpY2VfaWQiOiJYSFI5OTg4ODFUIiwic2l0ZV9pZCI6MSwibGFuZ3VhZ2UiOiJlbiIsImNvdW50cnkiOiJnYiIsInNpdGVrZXkiOiJ0ZXN0ZWNwdWtuZXRzb2xs.K5l6CR306NAH3Fgk-EDNjD0msWV6dj3yHQAGzLM9x9Q"}}

**Need in format :**
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkZXZpY2VfaWQiOiJYSFI5OTg4ODFUIiwic2l0ZV9pZCI6MSwibGFuZ3VhZ2UiOiJlbiIsImNvdW50cnkiOiJnYiIsInNpdGVrZXkiOiJ0ZXN0ZWNwdWtuZXRzb2xs.K5l6CR306NAH3Fgk-EDNjD0msWV6dj3yHQAGzLM9x9Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following regex pattern:

```
"token":"(.*?)"
```

Then, use `$1$` in the template section, to refer to the first capture group, which should be the JWT.